# Hide activity button in some fragments and show in some fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, button

I have a main activity that includes two buttons 'Submit' and 'Pick' and few images. Inside the activity i have two fragments named MyThings and MyPicks. I want to hide activity button 'Pick' in MyThings fragment but want to show in MyPicks fragment. How can i achieve this? Because i don't know how to initialize the button  which is in main activity to that fragment so that i can hide and show button in fragments. Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this situation.

1. One of them is that you have two methods in your `Activity` named
   `showButton()` and `hideButton()` and in that methods you hide and
   show button. In your `Fragment`s you can call these methods in
   `onCreateView()` Method since you can invoke `Activity` methods from
   `Fragment`.
2. Another way is you hide or show button in your `Activity` when
   creating and putting `Fragment` in the container. I prefer the
   second way.